# Etymology of -ова in Russian surnames

Tags: этимология, выбор-имени, морфология, суффиксы

How should the suffix of feminine surnames, e.g. Морозова, be considered from an etymological perspective?

Are *-ов* and *-а* etymologically distinct morphemes or parts of a single one?

Comment: -ов is suffix, -а is ending.

Answer (score 4):

It will be formed as the possessive form of a name or nickname:

> Иван: Иванова дочь Марья.
> Мороз: Морозов сын Василий.

`-а` is a distinct morpheme — an ending denoting case. The masculine nominative form is empty, but it becomes non-empty in other cases: (кому?) Иванову vs. Ивановой.

Comment: I am assigning surnames to their etymological roots. My query is. Should a name like Иванова be given as coming from the elements Иван + -ов + -а. Or would it be more correct to create a suffix (?) -ова (which in turn comes from -ов + -а)? On the Russian Wiktionary, they use -ов + -а.

Comment: -ов- is a suffix and -а is an ending (a distinct morpheme). "Иванов" just has an empty ending in nominative case.